# How to pass data from parent to parent in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, routes, vuex

I want to pass the property namePage from Home / About to Navbar

In router → index.js we have included the components: Home.vue and About.vue

I tried to send the data by route, but it does not work.

If I change the hook from **created()** to **mounted()**, the DOM renders the property **namePage**, but is not reactive to changing the **Home.vue** and **About.vue** components.

In development mode, in the VueJs tool, **$route.meta.namePage** is reactive.

My components:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <header>
    <Navbar/>
  </header>
  
  <main>
    <router-view/>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
  import Navbar from "....";
  export default {
    components: {Navbar}
  }
</script>
```

**Navbar.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h6> {{ namePage}} </h6>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   name: "Navbar",
   data() {
      return {
        namePage: ''
     }
   },
   created() {
     this.namePage = this.$route.meta.namePage;
  }
 }
</script>
```

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    text text
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   name: 'Home',
   created() {
    this.$route.meta.namePage = 'Home page';
   }
 }
</script>
```

**About.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
    text text
  </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
   name: 'About',
   created() {
    this.$route.meta.namePage = 'About page';
   }
 }
</script>
```

Use: Vue.js 3, Vuex and folder structure created with Vue CLI

Comment: Make the `namePage` in navbar a computed reading directly from `$route.meta.namePage`: 
`computed: { namePage() { return this.$route.meta.namePage } }`. Not to mention you don't even need it. You can use `$route.meta.namePage` directly in the template.

Answer (score 2):

Your Navbar component is created once and always visible so the created hook will run only once.

Have you tried:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h6> {{ $route.meta.namePage }} </h6>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Navbar",
}
</script>
```

you can also use a watcher:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h6> {{ namePage }} </h6>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Navbar",
  data() {
    return {
      namePage: '',
    };
  },
  watch: {
    '$route.meta.namePage': {
      immediate: true, // <-- let the watcher run on initial render too
      handler: namePage => {
        this.namePage = namePage;
      },
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

[Edit:] from comment below, You can make a computed property:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h6> {{ namePage }} </h6>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Navbar",
  computed: {
    namePage() {
      return this.$route.meta.namePage;
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why not `computed: { namePage() { return this.$route.meta.namePage } }`?

Answer (score 0):

As you have `vuex`, you can easily achieve that with actions/getters. Take a look at snippet bellow with simple example:

```js
Vue.component('Navbar', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h3> {{ page}} </h3>
      <a href="#" @click="navigate('Home')">Home</a>
      <a href="#" @click="navigate('About')">About</a>
    </div>
  `,
  computed: {
    page() {
      return this.$store.getters.getPage //
    }
  },
  methods: {
    navigate(path) {
      this.$store.dispatch('setPage', path) //
      this.$router.push({name: path})
    }
  }
})

const Home = {
  template: `
    <div class="home">
      Home page
    </div>
  `
};

const About = {
  template: `
    <div class="about">
      About page
    </div>
  `
};

const routes = [
  { path: '', component: Home, name: 'Home' },
  { path: '/1', component: About, name: 'About' },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    page: 'Home'
  },
  mutations: {
    updatePage(state, payload) {
      state.page = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setPage({ commit }, data) {
      commit("updatePage", data);
    },
  },
  getters: {
    getPage(state) {
      return state.page;
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  router,
  store
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <header>
    <navbar></navbar>
  </header>
  <main>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </main>
</div>
```